configuring HashIndex for rocksdb from Java
I'm using RocksDB 6.x and trying to understand what are the effective settings of it.
For example, doc says that I should explicitly enable HashIndex for table.
tableFormatConfig.setDataBlockIndexType(DataBlockIndexType.kDataBlockBinaryAndHash);

Table file is accompanied with file OPTIONS-XXX
it has entry:
data_block_index_type=kDataBlockBinarySearch

Does it mean that binary index will be enabled by default, but I can "override" it using API and use both Binary and Hash Index?
Is there any way to get effective options for table in runtime?
